# How to convert these into datetime objects?

Tags: python

I have a dataframe which has date and Time in 2 seperate columns. Both are string objects. How do I merge them in 1 column in such a way that it also becomes datetime object.

```
     date            Time       open    high          low        close       Symbol
0   1/29/2016   9:15:00 15140.15    15291.45    15136.85    15291.45    NIFTY BANK
1   1/29/2016   9:16:00 15300.70    15328.80    15292.05    15315.50    NIFTY BANK
2   1/29/2016   9:17:00 15320.95    15320.95    15261.05    15263.85    NIFTY BANK
3   1/29/2016   9:18:00 15263.05    15265.85    15236.85    15242.20    NIFTY BANK
4   1/29/2016   9:19:00 15243.15    15259.30    15240.00    15259.30    NIFTY BANK
```

desired output-

```
datetime
1/29/2016 9:15:00
1/29/2016 9:16:00
1/29/2016 9:17:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Use: [pd.to_datetime()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

```
df['datetime'] = df['date'] + ' ' + df['Time']

df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```